# Use CodeIgniter's core functionality only

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried this somehow, but cannot get around the fact of setting the APPPATH. What I want to do is to use CodeIgniter's libraries and core functions, not the whole MVC model but only the helpers built in.

How can I achieve this? I would like to include some `.php` file into my files as a bootstrap load and get access to all the functionality there is, from database configs to `$this->db->...` stuff, but not the "load view" and controller stuff.

Any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: I think some of those functions are just hard coded. And besides, how often someone needs to include just some of the parts and not the whole thing. I think you're question is a little bit odd.

Comment: It does indeed sound odd, I have to admit that. The thing is, I have a working infrastructure but had, for a site project, to extend the site with a CI installation. Now I don't want to redo all the previous work at once, but step by step integrate CI's functionality.

Comment: I've worked with CI for quite some time and I know that their aim is to give you a full package. CI is relied on so many different classes to run and since it's an MVC structure, defiantly there is no way to cut any particular part from it and bring it over.

Comment: Again, I have to agree. It's just a special case and I thought that a modify index.php would do the trick, possibly.

Comment: If you want helpers, why not just find individual wrappers that achieve what you're looking to do? For example, [Zebra Database](http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-database/) is an excellent alternative to CI's database helper

Comment: Thanks. The reason is that I don't want yet another framework nor helper - my current own and CodeIgniter are amost one too much already.

Comment: Alright. Finally I got what I wanted:

`code`$system_path = 'projects/system/';
 $application_folder = 'projects/application';
 define('BASEPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $system_path));
 define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));
 define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
 $routing['controller'] = "standalone";

 require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
 include APPPATH. "config/database.php";

 $ci = get_instance();
 $ci->load->database($db['default'], false, TRUE);

/* testing */
$ci->input->ip_address();
$ci->db->from('any_table')->get()->result_array();`code`